# Rails - grouped_collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm trying to get grouped_collection_select with the following

```
class User
  has_many :pages, :through => pages_users
end

class Page
  has_many :users, :through => pages_users
  # name - String
  # type - String
end

class PagesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page 
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and I want the drop down grouped by type with the name underneath. The example I've seen with city/country/continent, isn't as helpful as I'd like. What's the best way of doing this? I think I want something like ...

```
<%= grouped_collection_select(:user, :page_id, user.pages, :type, :name, ) %>
```

but this obviously isn't correct.

Any thoughts?

Edited to show the actual relationships through the pages_users table.

Comment: Should be has_many users (now fixed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I finally ended up with ...

```
<%= select_tag 'page_id', grouped_options_for_select(Page.for_select) %>
```

where the Page.for_select looks like ...

```
def for_select
  {
    'Type 1'   => type1.map { |p| [p.name, p.id] },
    'Type 2' => type2.map { |p| [p.name, p.id] }
  }
end
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I think that is not good idea put `for_select` method into model. Should be a helper method

Answer (score 2):

Looking at it as a simple one-to-may relationship,

```
class User
  has_many :pages
end

class Page
  # name - String
  # type - String
end

<%= grouped_collection_select(:user, :page_id, user.pages.map(&:type), :pages_by_type, :name, :id, :name ) %>
```

For this to work, you need a mechanism to find all pages for a given type.

Comment: If it is a many_to_many relationship, change them to has_and_belongs_to_many, as shown. Do you have a third users_pages relation table?

Comment: Yes, there's a pages_users table in the mix too. Apparently, I shouldn't have tried to simplify so much. I guess I'm wondering though, why the page's relationship to user is important. I'm really only interested in the pages that the user has. Am I missing something? Also, why collection_select as opposed to grouped_selection_select?

Comment: Looking at collection_select, it doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for. I'd like the optgroup tags for the page types and then the page names underneath.

Comment: Is pages_by_type a method on Pages? Is the type passed in and then you get back all the pages of that type? Also, in the map, I think it should be user.pages.map(&:type) (parens rather than curly braces). Also for clarification, the final :id is for the page and the :name is for the page also?

Comment: Changed map. Final id and name are on page. I have used this syntax with three tables rather than two, so need to test the pages_by_type part.

Comment: Thanks. Please edit my answer(or add UPDATE at the bottom of your question to reflect a final working version and may be changing the title to reflect that you have only two tables in a grouped_collection_select.